# Extracting field from both actual and expected objects when testing with AssertJ

Tags: java, testing, assertj

I would like to check that a list contains a sub-list of another list. Here's a dummy example of how I do it currently:

```
@Test
public void testExtracting() throws Exception {
    final List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    users.add(new User(5234, "Adam"));
    users.add(new User(4635, "David"));

    final List<User> newUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    newUsers.add(new User(6143, "Bob"));
    newUsers.add(new User(3465, "Cindy"));

    users.addAll(newUsers);

    assertThat(users).extracting("id").contains(newUsers.get(0).id, newUsers.get(1).id);
}

public static class User {
    public long id;
    public String name;

    public User(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve the same result in a more compact way, without overriding the `equals` method of `User` class? I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
assertThat(users).contains(newUsers.get(0), newUsers.get(1)).extracting("id");
```

Or, better yet:

```
assertThat(users).contains(newUsers.subList(0, 2)).extracting("id");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are able to add a `getId()` method to `User`, you can solve this with an extractor:

```
assertThat(users)
    .extracting("id")
    .containsAll(extractProperty("id").from(newUsers));
```

Without being able to change `User` (so no overriding `hashcode()` or `equals()`, or adding getters), you will need to extract the `id` from both sets and compare them. This worked for me, but I'll admit it's a bit ugly.

```
assertThat(users)
    .extracting("id")
    .containsAll(newUsers.stream().map(it -> it.id).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

What I'm doing is using assertJ to extract the id from the users set and Java 8 streams/map to get all the newUser ids in one collection. This way your `newUsers` collection can be arbitrarily large and you don't have to hard code the mapping yourself.

Note that the stream/map work in the second example is the same work being done in the first example by `extractProperty`, we're just doing it manually.

Comment: Actually, I do have getters, I guess I have oversimplified my example. That was a good catch on your part. Also, I was initially caught off guard because you changed `contains` to `containsAll`. I was also using `doesNotContain`, but it has its counterpart `doesNotContainAnyElementsOf`, so I think I'm good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a getter method for the `id` property and do this:

```
assertThat(users).usingElementComparator(Comparator.comparing(User::getId)).containsAll(newUsers);
```